# How to handle events in Custom Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I am trying to create a simple controller, here is my Generic.xaml;

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TopluNotEkle">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FileSelector}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:FileSelector}">

                    <Button BorderThickness="8,8,8,8" Background="Gray" x:Name="MainButton">
                        <Button.BorderBrush>
                            <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,64,64" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="LightGray">
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="DarkGray">
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                <GeometryGroup>
                                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50"/>
                                                </GeometryGroup>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Button.BorderBrush>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="BlueViolet" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">Drag & Drop</TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and this is my code behind

```
public class FileSelector : Control
{
    static FileSelector()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FileSelector), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FileSelector)));
        MainButton.Drop += myDrop;

    }

    static void myDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Fail("This is called");
    }
}
```

I am getting `The name MainButton does not exist in current context` error. I also tried setting `Drop = "myDrop"`, however, that also didn't work.

How can I listen to events on my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons have been assigned a name by the `x:Name` attribute for us to be able to find them in code and hook up their click event handlers. This is done by overriding the `OnApplyTemplate` in our Custom Control class.

Retrieve the Button from the template

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate() 
{ 
    Button mainButton = GetTemplateChild("MainButton") as Button; 
    if (mainButton != null) 
        mainButton.Click += MainBtnClick; 
}
```

Follow a complete tutorial like for example (but not necessarily)  this:  http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is not what you are setting as a 'Drop' value, it is the reference to the `MainButton` that is not available.

I think you are trying to create a custom control, which typically defined as `UserControl`, not as a part of `ResourceDictionary`. I might be wrong as I haven't worked with WPF for several years. Here is how to create user control:

```
<UserControl x:class= "YourNamespace.FileSelector" ... other xmlns garbage>

<Button BorderThickness="8,8,8,8" Background="Gray" x:Name="MainButton">
    <Button.BorderBrush>
        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,64,64" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="LightGray">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="DarkGray">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryGroup>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50"/>
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Button.BorderBrush>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="BlueViolet" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20">Drag & Drop</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Also check out this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm